# Crystal Reports - Comparing two numeric field values with a formula

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I thought this would have been a simple task, I want to change the font colour of a field in a Crystal Report if it differs from another field value. Essentially I have two numeric fields and want to change the font to red if they are different.

I have used the Format Editor>Font>Color formula method. I have tried the following code/s ...

```
if ToNumber({Petty_Cash.PettyCashandMoneyIntroduced}) = ToNumber({Petty_Cash.LessTotalPaymentsByPettyCash}) Then crBlack Else CrRed;


if {Petty_Cash.PettyCashandMoneyIntroduced} <> {Petty_Cash.LessTotalPaymentsByPettyCash} Then crRed Else CrBlack;
```

Neither of these will work, if I add a numeric value it will work....

```
if {Petty_Cash.PettyCashandMoneyIntroduced} >=90 Then crBlack Else CrRed;
```

I'm hoping it's something simple that I have overlooked.

Any ideas please?

Comment: The fields are running totals, it will work when used on individual records.